# RMS current through the diode?

Tags: ac, rms

[image: **enter image description here**]

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it seems to be a homework question without any initial effort shown by the OP to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The tool you're looking for is a [delta-wye transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform).

For example, at node B, three resistors intersect, forming a Y that connects nodes A, C, and G. Those three resistors could be replaced with three new resistors, one from A to C, one from A to G, and one from C to G. The value of each new resistor is calculated from the equations in that link. Afterward, node B no longer exists, simplifying your analysis.

Applying this transformation multiple times in different locations will eventually allow you to start applying series or parallel simplifications, eliminating resistors entirely. After enough transformations and combinations you'll find the equivalent resistance of the entire "cube" of resistors, as if it was a single resistor in series with the source and diode.

The RMS current through the diode is then the same as the RMS current through the resistor, since they're in series. RMS current is RMS voltage divided by resistance. RMS voltage of a full-wave rectified AC line is peak (10) divided by sqrt(2). But you don't have a full-wave rectifier, you have a half-wave rectifier. It's conducting half the time, and not the other half, so you divide by sqrt(2) again.

Comment: Your last sentence should say ".. so you divide by 2."

Answer (score 0):

Always look for symmetry first. Look at the cube. From the node where current through the diode enters a cube node (node **a**), there are exactly three paths branching out. Each of these paths are through an \$R_1\$. Now move your mind to each of the three nodes these paths can go, and note that at each of these nodes there are exactly two remaining paths (towards the exit node) and that in all three cases, these paths are all just \$R_2\$. Now move your mind to each of the three remaining nodes, again the only remaining path in any case is \$R_3\$. So all paths are the same, each traveling through an \$R_1\$, then an \$R_2\$, and then an \$R_3\$. Therefore, a current moving into node **a** branches equally in three directions. If the entering current is \$I\$, then \$I_{a \rightarrow b} = I_{a \rightarrow d} = I_{a \rightarrow f} = \frac{I}{3}\$. These three currents can each only split in two ways, equally. So: \$I_{b \rightarrow c} = I_{b \rightarrow g} = I_{d \rightarrow c} = I_{d \rightarrow e} = I_{f \rightarrow e} = I_{f \rightarrow g} = \frac{I}{6}\$. However, these currents sum in pairs, so: \$I_{c \rightarrow h} = I_{e \rightarrow h} = I_{g \rightarrow h} = \frac{I}{3}\$, again. (And finally, these three equal currents sum back together at node **g**.) The resistance is now very easy to get. Imagine \$I=1A\$. Then the first drop is \$\frac{I}{3}\cdot 3k\Omega = 1kV\$. The second drop is \$\frac{I}{6}\cdot 6k\Omega = 1kV\$. The third and final drop is \$\frac{I}{3}\cdot 9k\Omega = 3kV\$. The total resistance is then \$\frac{5kV}{1A} = 5k\Omega\$. No real need for any fancy analysis here. The symmetry is just too perfect to ignore.

That pretty much makes the rest easy. The diode is ideal, so you have a half-wave situation. And the voltage provides a peak of \$10V\$, so the RMS will be that value divided by 2 (a \$\sqrt{2}\$ twice over) or a total of \$5V_{RMS}\$. Divide that by the \$5k\Omega\$ and you get an answer of \$1\,mA_{\,RMS}\$. (I'm leaving out the calculus for that, but you can follow it at this link here: [Half-Wave Rectifier](http://www.etcs.ipfw.edu/~lin/ECET307/Fall2006/Lectures/4_ECET307Week4_F06.html).)